# Haskell List With Guards error

Tags: list, haskell, guard, list-comprehension, take

i am trying to write a very simple function in haskell to change a value in a list depending on an input as follows

```
update_game :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
update_game (x:xs) row take_amnt | row == 1 = x - take_amnt:xs
                                 | row == 2 = x : head(xs) - take_amnt : tail(xs)
                                 | row == 3 = x : head(xs) : last(xs) - take_amnt`
```

the first two cases work fine, however the last case is causing me problems and im not sure why, the errors i get are :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpT8b.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlz5t.png

Comment: In the Windows console, you can copy text by clicking the window icon, selecting “Mark”, making your selection, and hitting Enter to copy it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `:` should be a list, but `last(xs) - take_amnt` apparently yields only a single element. Try

```
row == 3 = x : head(xs) : [last(xs) - take_amnt]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
last(xs) - take_amnt
```

is an `Int`, but the second argument of `(:)` must be a list, since `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`.

If your lists are always three elements long (but then you should probably use a tuple instead of a list), as it seems, wrapping that in a `[ ]` would solve it with the correct semantics,

```
update_game :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
update_game (x:xs) row take_amnt | row == 1 = x - take_amnt:xs
                                 | row == 2 = x : head(xs) - take_amnt : tail(xs)
                                 | row == 3 = x : head(xs) : [last(xs) - take_amnt]
```

However, it would be better to pattern-match accordingly

```
update_game [x,y,z] 1 take_amnt = [x - take_amnt, y, z]
update_game [x,y,z] 2 take_amnt = [x, y - take_amnt, z]
update_game [x,y,z] 3 take_amnt = [x, y, z - take_amnt]
update_game _       _ _         = error "Invalid input"
```

or make it generic without pattern matching

```
update_game xs index take_amnt = zipWith (-) xs (replicate (index-1) 0 ++ take_amnt : repeat 0)
```

Comment: Your alternative `update_game` definition would yield an error whereas the original function would yield `[1]` for `update_game [1] 1 0`.

Comment: Well, it's based on the explicitly mentioned assumption that the lists always have exactly three elements.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe if i'm not mistaken, in the original code this would cause `head []` to be called, which would cause an error.

Comment: @WillNess: In `update_game [1] 1 0`, `row == 1` holds, hence `x - take_amnt:xs` is used; no `head` call there.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter in ":" should be a list, `last(xs) - take_amnt` gives an element only.

wrap it in "[]" which would be `[last(xs) - take_amnt]`